# Why do fermions not have a Bose-Einstein Condensate phase?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, fermions, bose-einstein-condensate

My misconception was that electrons were present in a BEC. However, how do fermions behave in low temperature and how does it differ from the behaviour of bosons?

Comment: In a Bose-Einstein condensate you have no electrons, only bosons. In a superconductor you have electrons which form Cooper pairs.

Comment: So when forming a BEC, how does a substance lose the electron?

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific. At the moment it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking about the electron clouds of neutral atoms forming a BEC? The edited question is completely different from the original, by the way.

Comment: My misconception arised from reading about how BEC behaves as a 'superatom'. Thank you for the clarification s

Comment: Yes @Mark Mitchison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron are spin 1/2 particles, and hence are fermions.

Fermions do not have a Bose-Einstein condensate phase (that is, as the name suggests, for bosons).

In some particular situation (low temperature etc) they can give rise to a Bose-Einstain condensate if they couple and form  bosonic two-electron states (Cooper pairs) but then it is really the couples that form a condensate, rather than the electrons

Addendum:

In general (an other example are alpha particles, that are bosons but made of nucleons that are fermions) as long as you are in conditions such that you can ignore the internal structure of the bosonic composite you can have a Bose-Einstein condensate.

Addendum II because the OP changed radically the question:

Electrons are fermions; fermions have antisymmetric wavefunction, that is, if the system have discrete energy levels, thy are subjected to Pauli exclusion principle, and therefore two electrons cannot occupy the same level.

Bosons, on the other hand, can "collapse" to the lowest energy level and this is the BE condensate

Comment: Why do fermions not have a BEC phase?

Comment: Because only bosons could form a BEC. For fermions it is possible that they form Cooper pairs and with this we have superconductivity.

Comment: I edited the answer to touch that issue

Comment: My question was based on a serious misconception and hence, had to be changed. One more question: Does the matter need to be anionic in order to form a BEC or can it be done using a neutral atom?

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking now; bosons can for BEC whereas fermions cannot. If you are considering a composite "particle" (like an atom, an alpha particle, a Cooper pair) that as a whole acts like a boson, it can condensate, but this is meaningful until you can consider the atom as a whole; if the conditions (energy, temperature etc) are such that the internal structure of your composite object becomes relevant than you are not talking about the composite object anymore

Comment: What is the distinction between a superfluid and a BEC? Is it that a superfluid has relatively strong interactions compared to the latter?

Comment: As fare as I know a superfluid is a fluid with zero viscosity, but I am not able to tell you more. Since we are moving from the initial topic I would suggest to open a new question